# Long and detailed AND,OR conditional IF statements on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement

Could you please tell me what my mistake is on the following code:

```
if ((i>156-9 && i<156+9) && (j>406-9 && j<406+9)) || ((i>684-11 && i<684+11) && (j>274-11 && j<274+11)) || ((i>1066-15 && i<1066+15) && (j>67-15 && j<67+15)) || ((i>1559-15 && i<1559+15) && (j>867-15 && j<867+15)) || ((i>1082-18 && i<1082+18) && (j>740-18 && j<740+18)) 
    plot(j, i, 'r+', 'MarkerSize', 7, 'LineWidth', 5);
end
```

I'd like to use an if statement which obeys to get in the expression if one of these conditions are fulfilled:

```
((i>156-9 && i<156+9) && (j>406-9 && j<406+9))  OR
((i>684-11 && i<684+11) && (j>274-11 && j<274+11)) OR
((i>1066-15 && i<1066+15) && (j>67-15 && j<67+15)) OR
((i>1559-15 && i<1559+15) && (j>867-15 && j<867+15)) OR
((i>1082-18 && i<1082+18) && (j>740-18 && j<740+18))
```

Thanks in advance...
Regards.

Comment: We don't know what is the mistake, if you do not tell us what is the error message or what are the actual output vs. expected output. In your case I think about the plot(i,j) instruction. i and j have to be arrays, so they can't be bigger or smaller than a single number.

Comment: @marcoresk you certainly can compare an array to a scalar value but you will get a logical array as the result. However if you try to use `&&` or `||` with logical array inputs you will get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your expression in the if as is and used this for this little piece of code.

```
clc; A=[];
for i=1:2000
     for j=1:2000
         if ((i>156-9 && i<156+9) && (j>406-9 && j<406+9)) || ((i>684-11 && i<684+11) && (j>274-11 && j<274+11)) || ((i>1066-15 && i<1066+15) && (j>67-15 && j<67+15)) || ((i>1559-15 && i<1559+15) && (j>867-15 && j<867+15)) || ((i>1082-18 && i<1082+18) && (j>740-18 && j<740+18)) 
            A = [A, num2str(i),' ',num2str(j), char(10)];
        end
     end
end
display(A);
```

It works for me.